# React.js 0.13 - Warning: Something is calling a React component directly. Use a factory or JSX instead

Tags: reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

Running the code below serverside, I get

> "Warning: Something is calling a React component directly. Use a
>   factory or JSX instead."

But I *am* using a factory in *server.js* (when not using JSX), and in the *components* I'm using JSX. So what's the problem?

Okay, then I tried to use a factory in Parent component (changed `var Child = require('./Child');` to `var Child = React.createFactory(require('./Child'));`
In this case server works OK, but client does NOT:

> instantiateReactComponent.js:43 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mountComponent' of undefined

So how can I make it run on server and client both?

**components/Parent.js:**

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var React = require('react');
var Child = require('./Child');

var Parent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="a-child">
                <Child />
            </div>
        )
    }
});

module.exports = Parent
```

**components/Child.js:**

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var React = require('react');

var Child = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <span>I'm a Child!</span>
        )
    }
});

module.exports = Child;
```

**server.js:**

```
var JSX = require('node-jsx').install();
var React = require('react');
var Parent = React.createFactory(require('./components/Parent'));
...
var markup = React.renderToString(Parent());
...
```

**client.js:**

```
var React = require('react');
var Parent = require('./components/Parent');
...
React.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of node-jsx are you using? JSX used to compile `<ComponentClass />` to `ComponentClass()`, so that's probably what's happening here.

Try updating node-jsx or [move to babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/) with the `require('babel/register')` hook.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I had 0.11.0, updated to 0.12.4 and now it works.